# Multiple or statements in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, grouping

I have a question. I have a quite big matrix with id numbers with values.
I would like to group them by specific ids for each group. The specific Ids are in the range of 50 to 150 unique ids.
I could write a loop or Or statement, which will do the trick but very slow as each of the files is about 2gb. Is there a possibility to use an array as input for Or statements?
e.g

```
   X=find(T.imonumber==9523366 | T.imonumber==6715334 | T.imonumber==6715334.....);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ismember` function to generate logical index then using `find` you can convert it to numeric index.

```
a = [9523366 , 6715334 ,6715334];
idx = ismember(T.imonumber, a);
x = find(idx);
```